# How to set a child's element 50px narrower to its parent element in css?

Tags: css

Most tutorials just tell me something like:

```
width: 100%;
```

or something like:

```
width: 200px;
```

However, I just want to set the width of child element 50px smaller than that of the parent element. And I will place another element in the spared 50px region, so margin or padding shouldn't work for me.

Comment: So use a margin or  padding ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are different ways to accomplish this. I think these are the two most obvious ones:

1. You could specify a margin

This makes it harder to position an extra element next to it, since the remaining space is still claimed by the margin on the child element.

```css
.outer {
  border: 1px solid blue;
}

.inner {
  border: 1px solid red;
  margin: 0 50px 0 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="outer"><div class="inner">Demo
```

2. Or you could use calc

This method is more convenient if you need to add an extra element next to it. You could use `float: left` or `display: inline-block` to help the next element to appear right of the child.

```css
.outer {
  border: 1px solid blue;
}

.inner {
  border: 1px solid red;
  width: calc(100% - 50px);
}
```

```html
<div class="outer"><div class="inner">Demo
```

3. Use Position: absolute

This can be very useful and powerful, but it has some side effects too. As you can see in the snippet, the parent element collapses in height and is unaffected by the side of the child. This might not be a problem, and can even be useful as long as you know what you're doing. The second child element could also be positioned in this way, by specifying a width (50px) and just the right position (0).

```css
.outer {
  border: 1px solid blue;
  position: relative;
}

.inner {
  border: 1px solid red;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div class="outer"><div class="inner">Demo
```

Comment: Added a third option and a small explanation how they would work with that second child.

Comment: I ask this question just because I don't know that percentage values and absolute values can appear in math operations simultaneously. I need to place another child element in the 50px region, so the second way should work for me.

Comment: It's said that my problem is too broad so I modified the description.